# JavaScript expired time

Tags: javascript, momentjs, unix-timestamp

I need a function that will add 24 hours to a unix timestamp. Then I need to check how much time is left between the creation of the timestamp and the 24th hour as time goes by. This will serve as an "expiration" feature. I tried using moment.js, but not sure if that will work. Any ideas?

Comment: Try Luxon instead of Moment. It is created by the same developers, and Luxon is the successor to Moment (end-of-life).

Comment: Also, what is the 24th hour? Can you provide an example of two dates and expected display?

Answer (score 1):

```js
const createExpiryUnix = (hours = 24) => (new Date(Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * hours)).getTime();
// returns timespan

const checkExpired = (unix) => unix < Date.now();
// returns true if expired
```

you can use these simple functions to create and check the expiry timespan.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/manual/math.html) instead of Moment. It is created by the same developers, and Luxon is the successor to Moment (end-of-life).

```js
const { DateTime } = luxon;

const addDays = (unixTimestamp, days = 1) =>
  DateTime.fromSeconds(unixTimestamp).plus({ days });

const checkExpiration = (unixTimestamp, expiration) =>
  ((current, now) =>
    (expiration !== undefined ? current > expiration : current < now)
      ? 'Expired'
      : `${
        (expiration !== undefined
          ? (expiration).diff(current, 'hours')
          : (current).diff(now, 'hours')
        ).as('hours').toFixed(0)
      } hours remaining`)
  (DateTime.fromSeconds(unixTimestamp), DateTime.local());

let now = DateTime.local();
let expiration = addDays(now.toSeconds());

console.log(`Time remaining: ${checkExpiration(now.toSeconds(), expiration)}`);
console.log(`Time remaining: ${checkExpiration(1620772138)}`); // From comment

futureDate = addDays(DateTime.local().toSeconds(), 2);

console.log(`Time remaining: ${checkExpiration(futureDate.toSeconds())}`);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/luxon/1.26.0/luxon.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Wow, this is pretty awesome! Thanks! Let me answer your question that you asked. The use case is, once the user clicks a button an object will be created. That objects' timestamp will be stored in the database. On the frontend I need to constantly check how much time is left until that object expires. For example - object created at noon today, I want it to expire at noon tomorrow (24 hours after), so it should display "expires 24 hours from now". 4 hours from now, when I check again, i'd like it to say "expires 20 hours from now" etc.

Comment: Your function is currently giving me the remaining time from now, but since these timestamps will be stored in the DB, i'll need to be able to pass in those timestamps. Where exactly do I pass in the timestamp variable?

Comment: @IGJ the `checkExpiration` function takes a (`Number`) `timestamp`.

Comment: Hmm, doesnt seem to be working. I tried passing in 1620772138 (which is Tues May 11 2021 17:28:58 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time), but I get ```Time remaining: 23 hours remaining```

Comment: @IGJ You passed seconds, not millis. I can fix this to multiply the 1000 seconds and divide them accordingly. Ok, I updated the `checkExpiration` function to expect seconds instead of milliseconds.

Comment: Hey Mr.Polywhirl, I tried with a timestamp from not long ago ```checkExpiration(1620998138)```and the result was "Expired". I would have expected the result to be "24 hours remaining" with a recent timestamp

Comment: @IGJ OK, so I tuned the function one more time. If you pass an expiration, the timestamp will be compared to that given time. If you did not pass an expiration, it will be treated as the current time.

Comment: What is the 'expiration' argument and how is it used? Is it the number of hours until expiration? Haha sorry, i'm just confused by how this works because it looks like I need to pass an expiration since the function expects 2 arguments, not 1. Can you show me how you would use this ```checkExpiration(1620998138)``` to check the remaining time of this timestamp in a 24 hour period or whether it has expired or not? Thanks for your help on this!

Comment: @IGJ The `expiration` param is a future date. This means that `unixTimestamp` will be subtracted from it to get the remaining hours. If you do not pass an `expiration`, the `unixTimestamp` will be compared to the current time.

Comment: Cool. I couldn't get it to work how I wanted, but I do appreciate you trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Moment.js, which was simple and worked for me.
`var exp = moment(new Date(expirationTimestamp)).from(new Date(now));`